# Get lightning datatable to stretch vertically to full height of parent container while retaining sticky header

Tags: css, lightning-datatable, style

I have a tab in salesforce where I have a header and a `<lightning-datatable>` below the header. Conveniently the datatable has an overflow-y built into it so that if you limit the height of the datatable container, it will produce a vertical scrollbar with a fixed table header so that you can scroll through the rows while the header is still visible - very nice.

Here's an example where I'm setting the height of the datatable container to 300px:

[image]

But what I ***want*** to do, as you can see in the screenshot annotation, is not hard-code a height, but rather have the table dynamically expand down to the full height of the container (in this case the tab, or the gray background), while still retaining the scrollbar and sticky header. I've done this before using flexbox (basically you make the container surrounding the table and header `display: flex`, then you would make the container immediately surrounding the table `flex-grow: 1`).

This basic layout is easy enough to do with simple divs, like in [my example here](https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/vYmxpdz), but once you add a `<lightning-datatable>`, it gets more complicated. [Here's what I have so far](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2y35tI7slckE29T89lse).

Comment: `slds-template__container` would normally expand the component to fit it's parents height, however, you will need to drill down and find what element needs the class